# no Xamarin portable class library

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to start a new Xamarin portable app in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017, and I do not see a Xamarin.Forms portable app template when I open the new project menu. I am not sure where to get it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Visual C# > Cross-Platform > Cross Platform App

[image]

Then select the Code Sharing Strategy: Portable Class Library (PCL)

[image]

Comment: but How do you get the version that puts all the content on the CS page, instead of on the XAML page